# Cut and paste in Vim without moving next line up

Tags: vim

When I cut and paste in VIM by pressing `v`, and go to the end of the line using `$`, and press `d`, the next line gets moved up to the same line I'm cutting.

How do I stop this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It moves up because you have removed all the characters including line return/feed.

There are multiple solutions as usual with Vim. There is no "one true way" but you can try the following commands.

- You can use `D` (capital) in normal mode which will erase everything until the end of line.

  See `:help D`
- Using another motion

  What you could do instead of using <kbd>$</kbd> to move to the end of the line, use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>_</kbd>. It will move to the last non blank character of the line and won't select line return.

  See `:help g_`

  So <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>_</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> should work as you want.
- Using Replace

  Alternatively, what you could do instead of cutting, you could replace the erased character by a blank using  the space character.

  So <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd> should work to erase but it will not save the replaced characters in register (for pasting later for example).

Answer (score 1):

To cut everything from current cursor position until the end, use <kbd>C</kbd>.

[`:he C`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#C) will help you:

> Delete from the cursor position to the end of the
>               line and [count]-1 more lines [into [register](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/sponsor.html#register) x], and
>               start insert.  Synonym for c$ (not |[linewise](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#linewise)|).

Doing so will cause the current line (assuming you are on the start of the line when hitting <kbd>C</kbd>) to become empty and the content is (by default) yanked into register `"`

---

Edit:
As Xavier notes in his comment (and his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317055/cut-and-paste-in-vim-without-moving-next-line-up/7317142#7317142)), the same could be achieved with [<kbd>D</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#D). It also cuts everything from current cursor position until the end of the line but doesn't go in insert mode after doing it.

Comment: I didn't know about `C`, but I am not sure that the OP want to replace the cut text. However, `D` exists and seems to work fine.

Comment: @Xavier: thanks for reminding me of `D`. Does almost the same except going to insert mode. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use these keystroke sequence then next line would not move up.

```
v $ h d
```

It is moving up because EOL character `$` is also getting deleted without moving cursor 1 character back.

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the visual mode and swap the other two commands, ie. press `d` `$`.

This is shorter than your starting one and doesn't break your tradition introducing other keystrokes you may not be familiar with.